# How do I add the values in an array, then output to a calculation function?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript. My question is - how would I add up values in an array like this:

```
var pizza = {
    Hawaiianvalue: 9.50,
    Cheesevalue: 9.50,
    Veggievalue: 9.50,
    Supremevalue: 9.50,
    Pepperonivalue: 9.50,
    MeatLoversvalue: 15.50,
    Chicken: 15.50,
    Prawnvalue: 15.50
};
```

and then output those values to a function similar to this:

```
function calculateTotalPrice(e){ 
var calc = (Hawaiianvalue + Cheesevalue + Veggievalue + Supremevalue + Pepperonivalue
    + MeatLoversvalue + Chickenvalue + Prawnvalue);
output1.value = calc; }
```

?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That is NOT an array. So reference the keys in the object `pizza.Hawaiianvalue + pizza.Cheesevalue + pizza.Veggievalue + ...`

Comment: Oh. In that case, I need an array, and then output that.

Comment: Why would you need an array?

Comment: a) you are presenting a dictionary, not an array b) why do you specifically want an array? c) I might suggest taking a basic instructed course such as the ones on Codecademy or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will certainly seek out instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate object using **[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** loop

```js
var pizza = {
  Hawaiianvalue: 9.50,
  Cheesevalue: 9.50,
  Veggievalue: 9.50,
  Supremevalue: 9.50,
  Pepperonivalue: 9.50,
  MeatLoversvalue: 15.50,
  Chicken: 15.50,
  Prawnvalue: 15.50
};

function calculateTotalPrice(e) {
  var calc = 0;
  for (var key in pizza) {
    if (pizza.hasOwnProperty(key))
      calc += pizza[key];
  };
  console.log(calc);
  return calc;
}

calculateTotalPrice();
```